# My php generated email is not showing all the records from my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know what is this not working the way I want it.. I have a database with a few records and the is query showing only the first row, instead of all.

```
<?php    
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost"," "," "," ");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM programari");
$to = "my_email@yahoo.com";
$subject = "testing mail";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {   
   $body= $row['cand'];  
  }

if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
}

?>
```

Comment: You are actually getting the last row of your result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accidentally assigning to `$body` instead of concatenating. Short and sweet:

```
$body .= $row['cand'];
```

Edit: you should also initialize `$body` to an empty string before your loop, to avoid a notice on the first run.

Comment: THANKS A LOT ! I tried to solve this for days and I didn't even think it was that simple ... thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not showing the last row instead of the first row?  It looks like you need to use the dot `.` to concatenate your string to the body instead of assigning it directly.

```
$body .= $row['cand'];
```

This will append each `$row['cand']` to the end of `$body`.  You can use a delimiter to break it up in your email like this:

```
$body .= $row['cand']."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is $body overwritten each time you run while.

Initialized to empty string before while and inside while use $body .= $row['cand'];